# I cannot read JSON correctly using the Gson library

Tags: java, json, gson

I need to read json by using `Gson` library, but i have an `Exception`:

> Exception in thread "main" com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException:
>   java.io.EOFException: End of input at line 1 column 2 path $.

**Java class**

```
class Data {

    public Data() {
    }

    int value;
    Data left, right, dad;

    public Data(int value, Data left, Data right) {
        this.value = value;
        this.left = left;
        this.right = right;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public Data getLeft() {
        return left;
    }

    public void setLeft(Data left) {
        this.left = left;
    }

    public Data getRight() {
        return right;
    }

    public void setRight(Data right) {
        this.right = right;
    }

}
```

The following code demonstrates when I tried to build an object from JSON

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("put your json");
String json = in.next();
test = gson.fromJson(json, Data.class);
```

**Json**

```
 {
  "value": 1,
  "left": null,
  "right": {
    "value": 2,
    "left": {
      "value": 3,
      "left": null,
      "right": {
        "value": 7,
        "left": null,
        "right": null
      }
    },
    "right": {
      "value": 4,
      "left": {
        "value": 6,
        "left": null,
        "right": null
      },
      "right": {
        "value": 5,
        "left": null,
        "right": null
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I don't understand what I have done wrong, please help me whomever can :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`in.next()` will read a single line. You need to build a `String` from ALL of the lines.

If you put the raw Json hard coded as a `String` it’ll probably be fine. And there are answers on this site for reading multiple lines from `System.in` if you need to do it that way (although you’ll probably need to include some way to indicate that you’re finished sending the data).

Comment: @НикитаСкубак If the answer met your expectations, please close the question